# wcf and session asmx rewrite

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asmx

I have a web service that uses Session.  I want to rewrite it as an WCF that can be hosted outside IIS.

What is the best way to replace session using WCF that wont tie me to IIS in my rewrite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wcf and session asmx rewrite with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654133/wcf-and-session-asmx-rewrite-with-silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wsHttpBinding` with Reilable Messaging and sessions which can be hosted outside IIS. Have a look here:

[how to enable WCF Session with wsHttpBidning with Transport only Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650738/how-to-enable-wcf-session-with-wshttpbidning-with-transport-only-security)