# Generate SessionId in WCF

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I want to generate a unique SessionId every time when the user Login. I have read various articles and found the below line useful

```
 var sessionId = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
```

But still I am getting null in SessionId.

Please give me some useful way.

Comment: duplicate-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121252/how-i-can-have-a-session-id-in-wcf-service

Comment: I am getting this error:

Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:/Service1.svc