# WCF Transport Security and Session Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I'm trying to implement Transport-Level security (using Windows authentication/credentials) via a wsHttpBinding. But I'm getting the following error: Binding validation failed because the WSHttpBinding does not support reliable sessions over transport security (HTTPS). The channel factory or service host could not be opened. Use message security for secure reliable messaging over HTTP.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsSecure">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="https://localhost:8000/MyService/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsSecure"
      name="wsBinding" contract="IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check these post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650738/how-to-enable-wcf-session-with-wshttpbidning-with-transport-only-security

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767102/wcf-sessions-with-a-wshttpbinding-and-without-windows-security

Comment: Yep I read over those two before I posted the question. The problem is I need this to be singleton and to use transport layer security.