# How to enable Session with SSL wsHttpBinding in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, session, ssl, https

I have a WCF Service with wsHttpBindings and SSL enabled, but I'd like to enable WCF sessions.

After changing SessionMode to required

```
SessionMode:=SessionMode.Required
```

I'm getting error described below.

> Contract requires Session, but Binding 'WSHttpBinding' doesn't support
>   it or isn't configured properly to support it.

Here's my sample application.

**App.config**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
      </system.web>
      <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
      app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
      <system.serviceModel>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <client />
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0" useDefaultWebProxy="false" allowCookies="true">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10240" />
              <!--reliableSession enabled="true" /-->
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" >
                  <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                </transport >
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="WcfServiceLib.TestService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
              contract="WcfServiceLib.ITestService">
              <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="Local Network" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://test/TestService.svc" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
              set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
              set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
              to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

**ITestService.vb**

```
  <ServiceContract(SessionMode:=SessionMode.Required)>
    Public Interface ITestService

        <OperationContract(IsInitiating:=True, IsTerminating:=False)> _
        Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    End Interface
```

**TestService.vb**

```
    <ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerSession, _ 
    ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete:=False, _ 
    ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single)>
        Public Class TestService
            Implements ITestService

            Private _user As User

            <OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired:=True)>
            Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String _
 Implements ITestService.GetData

                If _user Is Nothing Then

                    _user = New User()
                    _user.userName = "User_" & value
                    _user.userPassword = "Pass_" & value

                    Return String.Format("You've entered: {0} , Username = {1} , Password = {2} ", _
                                         value, _user.userName, _user.userPassword)
                Else
                    Return String.Format("Username = {1} , Password = {2} ", _
                                    _user.userName, _user.userPassword)
                End If

            End Function

        End Class
```

I tried all possible solutions, I could find, but nothing helped.

Some advice to enable *reliable sessions*, but it doesn't work with **ssl** (if only you have your custom binding), others advice to use **http** instead of **https**, but I'd like to enable Sessions with my current configurations, if it's possible.

Is there any approach to achieve this?

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason for enabling session state on wcf service? This could be a bottleneck if you are looking for high performace. Session state wcf service should be avoided.

Comment: I'd like to have a _user variable for every session. I get a new instance of service class for every call. _user's value is always Nothing.

Comment: What solution should I use for my situation, if I need to store data for every client?

Comment: You can store user variable inside wcf request custom header and read it on server side. Or you can read user identity from request. This will do the job for you.

Comment: I'd like to store variables on the server side without passing them to client and back.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want "sessions" with wsHttpBinding, you have to use either reliable messaging, or the security sessions. (source : [how to enable WCF Session with wsHttpBidning with Transport only Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650738/how-to-enable-wcf-session-with-wshttpbidning-with-transport-only-security)).

WSHttpBinding supports session but only if either security (SecureConversation) or reliable messaging are enabled.
If you are using transport security then it is not using WS-SecureConversation and WS-ReliableMessaging is turned off by default. Therefore the two protocols that WSHttpBinding uses for session are not available. You either need to use message security or turn on reliable session. (source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/57b3453e-e7e8-4875-ba23-3be4fff080ea/).

We’ve disallowed RM over Https in the standard bindings because the way to secure an RM session is to use a security session and Https does not provide session.

I found the msdn blurb about it here: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx
The blurb is “The only exception is when using HTTPS. The SSL session is not bound to the reliable session. This imposes a threat because sessions sharing a security context (the SSL session) are not protected from each other; this might or might not be a real threat depending on the application.”

However you can do it if you determine there is no threat. There is an RM over HTTPS sample via custom binding http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735116.aspx (source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/fb4e5e31-e9b0-4c24-856d-1c464bd0039c/).

To sum up your possibilities you can either :

1 - Keep wsHttpBinding, remove transport security and enable reliable messaging

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bindingConfig">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

But you loose the SSL layer and then part of your security.

2 - Keep wsHttpBinding, keep transport security and add message authentication

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

You get to keep your SSL security layer but your client will have to provide credentials (of any form) and even if you don't validate them at the service side, fake ones must still be provided as WCF will reject any message not specifying credentials.

3 - Use a custom binding with reliable messaging and HTTPS transport

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="bindingConfig">
      <reliableSession/>
      <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

I can't see any downside to this except the threat explained in MSDN, and it depends on your application.

4 - Use other session providers
If your application is hotsed in IIS, you could set

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

and depend on the

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

for your state.

Or implementing your own cookies.

PS : Note that for all those WCF configuration, I only tested service activation, not calls.

EDIT : As per user request, `wsHttpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` security mode implementing sessions (I'm not too familiar with VB.NET so pardon my syntax) :

Service code snippet :

```
<ServiceContract(SessionMode:=SessionMode.Required)>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()> _
    Sub SetSessionValue(ByVal value As Integer)

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function GetSessionValue() As Nullable(Of Integer)

End Interface

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerSession, 
    ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single)>
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Private _sessionValue As Nullable(Of Integer)

    Public Sub SetSessionValue(ByVal value As Integer) Implements IService1.SetSessionValue
        _sessionValue = value
    End Sub

    Public Function GetSessionValue() As Nullable(Of Integer) Implements IService1.GetSessionValue
        Return _sessionValue
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyUserNamePasswordValidator
    Inherits System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator

    Public Overrides Sub Validate(userName As String, password As String)
        ' Credential validation logic
        Return ' Accept anything
    End Sub

End Class
```

service Configuration snippet :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="bindingConf"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="bindingConf">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication 
            userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.MyUserNamePasswordValidator, WcfService1"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client test code snippet :

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Parallel.For(0, 10, Sub(i) Test(i))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Test(ByVal i As Integer)
        Dim client As ServiceReference1.Service1Client
        client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "login"
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"
        Console.WriteLine("Session N° {0} : Value set to {0}", i)
        client.SetSessionValue(i)
        Dim response As Nullable(Of Integer)
        response = client.GetSessionValue()
        Console.WriteLine("Session N° {0} : Value returned : {0}", response)
        client.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I don't have time to test your solutions, bounty ends in 10 minutes, but this answer is the most detailed, so I'll accept it. It's suitable for me to use custom binding or TransportWithMessageCredential mode. I'll try them both. Thank you.

Comment: TransportWithMessageCredential won't work with wsHttpBinding. It works only with NetHttpBinding. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx

Comment: It means the only possible way for me is using a custom binding.

Comment: @hgulyan Why wouldn't `TransportWithMessageCredential` work with `wsHttpBinding` ? It's a fairly common scenario. From your link : WSHttpBinding :
Security : Transport, (Message), Mixed ; 
Session : (None), Reliable Session, Security Session

Comment: according to msdn wsHttpBinding doesn't support TransportWithMessageCredential . Did you check the link?

Comment: @hgulyan I think that's just the defaults, I tried it and it works perfectly, session enabled. I can edit the answer to show the full code sample.

Comment: Please ask an other question on how to implement `TransportWithMessageCredentials` with WCF session enabled, answering here would pollute this question's main topic. (or look if any has already been answered before).

Answer (score 1):

By default, WSHttpBinding only allows security sessions. It is a concept of WCF and is not linked to Transport. A security session is not a session over https, but a session with mutual authentication. This is achieved by adding message security.

Based upon your service, you should apply this config

```
 <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <!-- configure transport & message security here if needed-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

On clientside, here is a simple unit test

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestSecuritySession()
    {
        //remove this is certificate is valid
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; });

        var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security = new WSHttpSecurity() { Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential};
        ChannelFactory<ITestService> Factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/TestService.svc"));

        Factory.Open();
        var channel = Factory.CreateChannel();

        //call service here

        (channel as IClientChannel).Close();

        Factory.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Will my session work in your case, if I make InstanceContextMode PerSession?

Comment: @hgulyan Yes of course. You can easily test this behavior from your side by returning session/instance specific data in one service method.

Answer (score 1):

wsHttpBinding requires reliableSession to support WCF sessions, and reliable sessions require custom binding to support ssl. So asking for WCF sessions over ssl and with wsHttpBinding seems like out of the question as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suppose, you're right, but what should I do, if I need both ssl and session working?