# How to use HTTPS with WCF SessionMode.Required - simplest possible example

Tags: c#, wcf, https, wcf-binding

**UPDATE (8/7/2014) - The solution to this problem was that I needed to add a class that derived from "UserNamePasswordValidator" and register it in Web.Config.**

I have created a simple test WCF service and test console client application (see below for code).  I am using .NET 4.5.1.  I have already searched for duplicates on StackOverflow (found similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578409/how-to-enable-session-with-ssl-wshttpbinding-in-wcf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650738/how-to-enable-wcf-session-with-wshttpbidning-with-transport-only-security)) - however I feel that the referenced posts are potentially outdated, and also feel that my post is more limited in scope.

OK now for the example:

The solution currently uses sessions (in ITestService.cs):

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

... and uses wsHttpBinding (see below app.config and web.config).

When I deploy this to a server, I am successfully able to access it via a web browser using HTTPS like this: https://myserver.com/test/testservice.svc

However, when I change the endpoint in the client app.config from:

```
http://localhost:20616/TestService.svc/TestService.svc
```

to:

```
https://myserver.com/test/testservice.svc
```

and run the console application again, I receive the error: "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via"

**My question is, what is the minimum changes I need to make for this to work, without changing SessionMode.Required?**

Here is the client console application code.  Please be sure to change the App.Config value for "mycomputer\Matt" to the correct value for your machine.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to log in...");
            try
            {
                TestServiceReference.TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceReference.TestServiceClient();

                bool loginSuccess = client.LogIn("admin", "password");
                if (loginSuccess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully logged in.");
                    string secretMessage = client.GetSecretData();
                    Console.WriteLine("Retrieved secret message: " + secretMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Log in failed!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: " + exc.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITestService"/>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="https://myserver.com/test/testservice.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="TestServiceReference.ITestService" name="WSHttpBinding_ITestService">
            <identity>
              <userPrincipalName value="mycomputer\Matt"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
            <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:20616/TestService.svc/TestService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="TestServiceReference.ITestService" name="WSHttpBinding_ITestService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="mycomputer\Matt"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>-->
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WCF Service code.

ITestService.cs:**

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfSessionsOverHttpsTest
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface ITestService
    {

        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
        bool LogIn(string username, string password);

        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
        bool LogOut();

        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
        string GetSecretData();
    }
}
```

**TestService.svc:**

```
namespace WcfSessionsOverHttpsTest
{    
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
        bool ITestService.LogIn(string username, string password)
        {
            if (username == "admin" && password == "password")
            {
                IsAuthenticated = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsAuthenticated = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool ITestService.LogOut()
        {
            IsAuthenticated = false;
            return true;
        }

        string ITestService.GetSecretData()
        {
            if (!IsAuthenticated)
            {
                throw new System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException("User has not logged in.");
            }
            else
            {
                string secretMessage = "The Red Sox are going to win the World Series in 2016";
                return secretMessage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfSessionsOverHttpsTest.TestService">
        <endpoint address="/TestService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WcfSessionsOverHttpsTest.ITestService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Thanks in advance for any help!**

Matt

Comment: As a minimum to enable HTTPS/SSL you need `<security mode="Transport">` in your binding.

Comment: I added <security mode="Transport" /> to both the client and service bindings.  Now I get the following exception message on the client: "Contract requires Session, but Binding 'WSHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."

Comment: Adding: <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security> to both the client and service bindings results in There was no endpoint listening at https://myserver.com/test/testservice.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Inner Exception message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." is obviously a misleading error.  https://myserver.com/test/testservice.svc still works in a browser (note: the domain is obviously not myserver.com, but I've used that to hide my actual domain).  Thank you.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I don't have specific experience with your exact (desired) configuration. My suggestion would be to enable WCF tracing and to take a look at the resulting logs. They often have more verbose diagnostics than just the exception message.

Comment: Basically at a dead-end it seems.  SessionMode.Required doesn't seem to be well documented or supported by Microsoft.  WCF tracing and resulting logs yielded no additional hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that I needed to add a class that derived from "UserNamePasswordValidator" and register it in Web.Config.

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyProgram.CustomUserNameValidator,MyProgram" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```